# How to find the Time Difference between a PM time and AM time?

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon

In my form there are 2 Time Pickers where user can select a from time and to time. It doesn't have a date associated with it. And for a report generating purpose I've to calculate the time difference between them. It works perfectly to if the From and to Time is "06:00 to 10:00" but if the from and to time is "21:00 to 02:00" I get a time difference of 19 hours. Could you please help me to fix this.

For this case "21:00 to 02:00" the time difference should be 5 hours.

This is the Code

```
$datetime1 = new \DateTime('09:30 PM');
$datetime2 = new \DateTime('02:00 AM');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%hh');

exit;
```

Comment: It's because PHP by default assumes today's date i.e. 2020-04-01. So internally it shows the difference between `2020-04-01 21:30:00` and `2020-04-01 02:00:00`, which is logically correct. One question here, will your `datetime2` be always greater than `datetime1`?

Comment: @Samir 

Not always. It depends

Comment: Just noticed in your question, from time and to time. So technically speaking, `from` time will always be smaller than `to` time. With this I mean if user selects from as 5 pm and to as 8 pm, it means timings are from same day. But if user selects from as 9.30 pm and to as 2 am it means timings are from 2 different dates i.e. 2020-04-01 21.30:00 and 2020-04-02 02:00:00. If this is the case then there is a solution. Kindly confirm.

Comment: Yes, How do you think we can solve this?

Comment: Comparing times will solve the issue. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 2 date pickers one for `from` time and another `to` time, the former will always be smaller than the latter. Hence when `from` time is larger than `to` time it means user has selected `to` from the next day. If we don't add a date for calculating difference, PHP will assume today's date by default. We can easily fix this by adding a condition to compare the times and prepend the dates accordingly. Below is the updated code.

```
<?php

$fromtime = '09:30 PM';
$totime = '02:00 AM';
$now = new \DateTime();
$today = $now->format('Y-m-d'); // Store current date

$now->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); // Add one day to current date to get next date
$nextDay = $now->format('Y-m-d'); // Store next date

if($fromtime > $totime) // If from time is bigger than to time, it means to is a next day
{
    $fromdatetime = "$today $fromtime";
    $todatetime = "$nextDay $totime";
}
else
{
    $fromdatetime = "$today $fromtime";
    $todatetime = "$today $totime";
}

$datetime1 = new \DateTime($fromdatetime);
$datetime2 = new \DateTime($todatetime);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%hh');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference becomes negative If $totime is less than $fromtime.
DateInterval->invert == 1 indicates that. This is used with this short solution to correct the result.

```
$fromtime = '09:30 PM';
$totime = '02:00 AM';

$diff = date_create($fromtime)->diff(date_create($totime));
$hours = $diff->invert ? 24-$diff->h : $diff->h;

echo $hours;  //5
```